# Is it possible to force refresh the page from js in Chrome/Safari? (needed for PWA updates)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, safari, progressive-web-apps

I currently have a PWA built using the Vue CLI - this uses the `workbox-webpack-plugin` under the hood. More info [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v3/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa).

My app update process was quite simple, and worked until about a week ago. I wrote a 'Service Worker Manager' - a global object that handled the service worker state changes. When the updated event fired, I would pop up a dialog asking the user to update. If they agreed, I would fire off a standard looking `window.location.reload(true)` and the new service worker would be installed and running.

Recently, `window.location.reload(true)` does not appear to force reload the page in Chrome (v79, desktop and mobile) or Safari (mobile, not sure which version). It does work as intended in Firefox.

Is there some alternative method for forcing a reload or otherwise updating a PWA in Chrome or Safari? The only 'user friendly' method I have at the moment is asking them to close the app, clear it from recent apps, and open it again. Not ideal at all.

Thanks!

Comment: May you share a bit of your code ?

Comment: Please update your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem (specifically, the `location.reload(true)` not reloading the page). You can create a runnable MRE using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Just checked Chrome v79.0.3945.130. Works just fine.

Comment: Might it be an issue with errors in your service worker. Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @KillianC and @T.J Crowder - There's not much to show really. `location.reload(true)` does reload the page, it just doesn't seem to force 'no-cache'. In Firefox, it works as expected. As an example, I tried the Vue.js cli docs - they have a popup saying "an update is available". Running `location.reload(true)` doesn't install the new service worker, but I did see that their refresh button calls `skipWaiting()` on the Service Worker. That may be the answer I needed.

Edit: I am not sure how to show this lack of caching in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @PascalZaugg I don't see any issues with it, no logs in the console or anything. I also suspected that may have been the case, but the fact that it works in Firefox seems to suggest otherwise.